# dropdown box in "new" email dialog

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I want to add - dropdown menu in "new" email dialog in outlook 2010.

Can any one tell me how can i add dropdown or propulte menu list in new email dialog window.
this selected email (from drop down) will be use as sender email address.

it would be great if dropdown list can be place at just above the TO , CC button as this will be use as "Sender".

Thanks
dhaval soni

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button to the ribbon interface on the new email dialog....and then host a drop down control on there? I'm not sure if it's possible to add a button directly above the 'From/To' buttons.

Comment: can you give any stuff or documentation link?

Comment: Here you go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172(v=office.14).aspx